# Changing cursor to custom one in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change a cursor in my React app to custom one, however I just cant acheive that.

I confirmed that doing:

```
<div style={{cursor: 'crosshair'}}></div>
```

works, however when I try to use my cursor those ways:

```
import swordIcon from '../sword.ani'
style={{cursor: swordIcon}}
```

or

```
 style={{cursor: `${swordIcon}, auto`}}
```

or path

```
style={{cursor: 'url("../sword.ani"), auto'}}
```

None of it works. In the last example i get 
"Proxy error: Could not proxy request /assets/sprites/cursor/sword.ani from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/"
However I dont think that disabling proxies would change anything here

Comment: Are you able to get this sword image through browser?

Comment: Are you use any bundle system? Webpack or rollup?

Comment: @RomanUnt I use create-react-app so webpack

Comment: @fard yes, I also tried some pngs, they all work, however not for cursor

Comment: @knightburton It doesnt matter if its png or .ani, this way im getting proxy issues and I cant really turn this proxy off :(

Comment: Just for the sake of testing i turned off the proxy, i dont get error, but I also dont have new cursor anyway

Comment: is this cursor in /public/ directory?

Comment: @fard Nope, in my assetts folder

Comment: @BigPaws did you ever find a solution? I have exactly the same problem